# floating 2 columns side byside in container div

Tags: css, html, containers

I am trying float two columns called column_l and column_r side by side on an about page but the problem I am having is that its moves and messes up the footer and hangs outside of the container div.

column_l contains the info about the company while column_r contains a picture.

I will show my code, but basically, the body contains a container which I have put all my code on.

For this, I created a wrapper to include the two columns.

```
    body{
    background-image:url('../img/small_logo.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    position:relative;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    /*padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;*/
    overflow:visible;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    min-height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    /* FOR A LARGE-SINGLE IMAGE TO STRETCH COMFORTABLY ACROSS A BODY
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    zoom:1;*/
    }
#container{
    margin: auto;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#F5F5DC;
    width:720px;
    border:2px black solid;
    position:relative;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-bottom:15px

}
#logo{ margin:0;
padding:auto;
position: inherit;
display:block;
height:auto;
width:auto;
}
#wrapper{margin:auto; height:auto; width:100%;}
#column_l {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    float:left;
}
#column_r {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right:0px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    position: absolute;
    left:60%;

}

#column_r p {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 7px;
}

#nav{
    background-color: #800000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 2px solid #800000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #800000;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    font-family:"Buxton Sketch";
    font-size:16px;
}
#rightContainer{
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:2px solid;
width:25%;
height:400px;

}
th{font-size:large;
}
#footer{
    margin-left:0;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0.6em;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    height:40px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-family:"Buxton Sketch";
    font-size:16px;

    }

#copyright{
    margin:auto;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;

}
#copyright p{
font-size: 12px;
  color:#000000;

}
#fb {padding:2px;margin:auto; float:left; }

/* Styles for Navigation */
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
}
#nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline;

}
#nav a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #456;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
    font-size:large;
    color:black;
}
/* Styles for Footer */
#footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
#footer li {
    float: left;
}
#footer a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline;

}
#footer a:hover {
    border: 1px solid ;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
    font-size:medium;
}

/*Classes */
.largehead h1{font-size:x-large;}
.shadow:before,
        .shadow:after {
            content:"";
            position:absolute;
            z-index:-2;
        }

        .shadow p {
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .shadow img {
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

/* Shadow Style */
.shadow {
 -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px lightblue;    /*   For Older Versions    */
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px lightblue;  
        box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px lightblue;   

        /*                   For  'IE'                                */

        filter:
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=lightblue,direction=0,strength=5)   /*  Top     */
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#777777,direction=90,strength=3)    /*  Right   */
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#777777,direction=180,strength=3)   /*  Bottom  */
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=lightblue,direction=270,strength=5);/*  Left    */
    }
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px lightblue;  
        box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black,-2px -2px 5px lightblue;   

        /*                   For  'IE'                                */

        filter:
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=lightblue,direction=0,strength=5)   /*  Top     */
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#777777,direction=90,strength=3)    /*  Right   */
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#777777,direction=180,strength=3)   /*  Bottom  */
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=lightblue,direction=270,strength=5);/*  Left    */
    }
/* Rotated box*/

        .rotated {
            -webkit-box-shadow:none;
               -moz-box-shadow:none;
                    box-shadow:none;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
               -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
                -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
                 -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
                    transform:rotate(-3deg);
        }

        .rotated > :first-child:before {
            content:"";
            position:absolute;
            z-index:-1;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            background:#fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
               -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
                    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        }

        /* Lifted corners */

        .lifted {
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
                 border-radius:4px;
        }

        .lifted:before,
        .lifted:after {
            bottom:15px;
            left:10px;
            width:50%;
            height:20%;
            max-width:300px;
            max-height:100px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
               -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                    box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
               -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
                -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
                 -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
                    transform:rotate(-3deg);
        }

        .lifted:after {
            right:10px;
            left:auto;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
               -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
                -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
                 -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
                    transform:rotate(3deg);
        }

 /* Curled corners */

        .curled {
            border:1px solid #efefef;
            -moz-border-radius:0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 6px 6px;
                 border-radius:0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 6px 6px;
        }

        .curled:before,
        .curled:after {
            bottom:12px;
            left:10px;
            width:50%;
            height:55%;
            max-width:200px;
            max-height:100px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
               -moz-box-shadow:0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                    box-shadow:0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -webkit-transform:skew(-8deg) rotate(-3deg);
               -moz-transform:skew(-8deg) rotate(-3deg);
                -ms-transform:skew(-8deg) rotate(-3deg);
                 -o-transform:skew(-8deg) rotate(-3deg);
                    transform:skew(-8deg) rotate(-3deg);
        }

        .curled:after {
            right:10px;
            left:auto;
            -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
               -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
                -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
                 -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
                    transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
        }
        dl.border-around
{
    margin: 2em 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20em;
    float:right;
}

.border-around dt
{
    background-color: #131210;
    color: #959289;
    padding: .5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 1px solid #131210;
    border-right: 1px solid #131210;
    border-top: 1px solid #131210;

}

.border-around dd
{
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    background: #DBD8D8;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em .5em;
    font-style: italic;
    border-left: 1px solid #131210;
    border-right: 1px solid #131210;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131210;

}

div.wrapperleft{
    float:left;
    position:relative;

    }
}
    div.wrapper{  
        float:right; /* important */  
        position:relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */  
    }  
    div.description{  
        position:absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/  
        bottom:0px; /* position will be on bottom */  
        left:0px;  
        width:60%;  
        /* styling bellow */  
        background-color:black;  
        font-family: 'tahoma';  
        font-size:15px;  
        color:white;  
        opacity:0.6; /* transparency */  
        filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* IE transparency */  
    }  
    p.description_content{  
        padding:0px;  
        margin:0px;  
    }  

        /*Feedback*/
form {float:left; width:50%; text-align:left; padding-top:30px;color:white; margin-left:200px; list-style:none;}
textarea {border:0; padding-top:0px; font-family:"Lucida Console";}
input {border:0; padding:0; font-family:"Lucida Console";}
submit {border:0; padding:0; font-family:"Lucida Console";}
label {border:0; padding:0; font-family:"Lucida Console";}
label {float:left; width:150px; text-align:right; display:block;margin-top:5px;}
textarea {border:1px gray solid; margin-left:10px; padding:5px;}
input, datalist {border:1px gray solid; margin-left:10px; padding:5px;}
input {width:280px; margin-bottom:16px;}
textarea {width:280px; height:150px; text-align:justify; margin-bottom:16px;}

#feedback {padding-top:10px; margin-right:100px;}
```

and for the html:

```
 <body > <!-- START BODY -->
<!-- START CONTAINER -->
    <div id="container" class="shadow lifted"> 
        <div id="logo">  <!-- START LOGO -->
            <img src="img/cropped_logo.jpg" alt="logo" width=720px height=300px />
        </div> <!-- END LOGO -->
        <!-- START NAV-->
    <div id="nav" class="shadow">
        <a href="index.html" > Home</a>
        <a href="menu.html"> Menu</a>
        <a href="wholesale.html">Wholesale</a>
        <a href="story.html">Our Story</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div> <!-- END NAV-->
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Begin Left Column -->
        <div id="column_l">
            <h1>Our Story</h1>
            <p> What started out as making ice cream for family and friends, in our home kitchen, quickly flourished into a labor of love and creativity for ice cream aficionado Hugh Balthrop. "For me, ice cream is all about real flavor using natural and local ingredients. This is where the passion is for me. Ice cream brings out the inner kid in everyone". Ever had Sweet Potato Ice Cream with candied pecans? What about lemon sweet tea sorbet? Wild Blueberry Frozen Yogurt? Blackberry or Watermelon Sorbet? The list goes on and on... Where can you find it, you ask? Right now, you can grab some at Oxbow Restaurant, in Clarksdale, MS, Mississippi Grounds and Cleveland Country Club in Cleveland, MS, Delta Bistro and TurnRow Books, in Greenwood, MS.</p>
        </div><!-- End Left Column -->
<!-- Begin Right Column -->
        <div id="column_r">
            <img alt="" height="288" src="img/hugh.jpg" width="193" />
            <p>Hugh Balthrop</p>
        </div><!-- End Right Column -->
        </div><br> <!--end wrapper-->






    <div id="footer" class="shadow lifted">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Sweet-Magnolia-Ice-Cream-Co/303952586284264?fref=ts" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" clear:both></div>


            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="menu.html"> Menu</a>
            <a href="wholesale.html">Wholesale</a>
            <a href="story.html">Our Story</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div> <!-- end of footer -->
        <div id="copyright" class="lifted">
            <p id="copyright">Sweet Magnolia Ice Cream Company &copy; 2013. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
</div> <!-- End of Container -->

</body>

</html>
```

I tried pushing column_r over with left:60% but it now covers up the footer.

Comment: Is it possible for you to set up a fiddle of this to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to clear the floats.

Add

```
#footer { clear: both; }
```

And it will fix the problem.

Comment: i've done this and it worked, but now i am trying to get the div fb to work so that it shows up in the footer

Comment: I don't see the javascrip code for the facebook plugin...You forgot to add it ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
float:left;
```

to the #wrapper CSS class will make the outer containing div expand to hold the contents of the article.

There are still some left over style issues you will have to deal with but hopefully this gets you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule 'clear: both; to the footer css styling, should do the trick!